# Upgrading ActiveRecord ODBC adapter: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby, odbc

I am getting this error when I use the ODBC adapter. Could it be that my versions don't match? It looks like I'm using activerecord-odbc-adapter-2.0 with activerecord-3.1.0.

```
    wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-odbc-adapter-2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/odbc_adapter.rb:765:in `select_all'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:470:in `find_by_sql'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:111:in `to_a'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:15:in `each'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/app/controllers/states_controller.rb:15:in `block in update'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/app/controllers/states_controller.rb:12:in `update'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:97:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:191:in `new'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:191:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `start_load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:298:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:147:in `block in run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:146:in `run'
    ./data_exchange_preview:15:in `<main>'
    Connection refused - connect(2)
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:551:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:551:in `open'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87:in `timeout'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:551:in `do_start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:463:in `start'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/app/controllers/controller.rb:21:in `send_notification'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/app/controllers/controller.rb:29:in `handle_exception'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/app/controllers/states_controller.rb:45:in `rescue in update'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/app/controllers/states_controller.rb:4:in `update'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:97:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:191:in `new'
    /usr/local/www/sl-exchange/lib/exchange.rb:191:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:203:in `start_load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:298:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:147:in `block in run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:146:in `run'
    ./data_exchange_preview:15:in `<main>'
```

Here's the line in my code where it fails:

states_controller.rb:

```
class StatesController < Controller

def update()    
    ...
        Web::State.transaction do #<-- this is line 12

            nti_states.each do |state| #<-- line 15
                ...
```

(This is just a ruby app. Not rails) Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a gem compatibility problem. As of ActiveRecord 3.1.0 in 2011, `select_all` takes a third argument which the (admittedly latest) ODBC 2.0 adapter does not support, since it dates back to 2008.  See https://github.com/santana/activerecord-informix-adapter/issues/4 for a related Informix adapter problem.

It's hard to believe that no one has provided an updated ODBC adapter, and perhaps harder to believe that no one has complained about this in an SO-visible way, but perhaps that's the case.  Oh, how the mighty have fallen. ;-)

Here's a related excerpt from Wikipedia:

> ODBC today
>
> ODBC remains largely universal today, with drivers available for most
>   platforms and most databases. It is not uncommon to find ODBC drivers
>   for database engines that are meant to be embedded, like SQLite, as a
>   way to allow existing tools to act as front-ends to these engines for
>   testing and debugging. However, the rise of thin client computing
>   using HTML as an intermediate format has reduced the need for ODBC.
>   Many web development platforms contain direct links to target
>   databases - MySQL being particularly common. In these scenarios, there
>   is no direct client-side access nor multiple client software systems
>   to support, everything goes through the programmer-supplied HTML
>   application. The virtualization that ODBC offers is no longer a strong
>   requirement, and development of ODBC is no longer as active as it once
>   was.